# Passing a string from 1 window to another - XAML

Tags: c#, xaml

I have 2 windows, when a button is clicked on the first window the second will appear prompting the user to select/upload an image. All related XAML objects are created and styled.

Question: How do I get the string value of the sourcefile from the second window to appear in a textblock on the first window?

Open Window & Get string value of sourceFile Code:

```
        private void btn_Image_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Create the window
        AddImage AddImageScreen = new AddImage();
        AddImageScreen.Owner = this;
        // Open and show the window
        AddImageScreen.ShowDialog();

        txtblock_ImgAddress = // How do I get the image source file here?
    }
```

Select/Upload Image Code:

```
     public partial class AddImage : Window
{

    string imageDirectory;

    public AddImage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
        dlg.Filter = "Images (*.JPG;*.JPEG;*.PNG) | *.JPG;*.JPEG;*.PNG";
        Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

        string sourceFile = "";
        string fileName = "";

        if (result == true)
        {
            sourceFile = dlg.FileName;
            fileName = sourceFile.Substring(sourceFile.LastIndexOf('\\'));
            var SourceFile = sourceFile;

        }

        string destinationFile = imageDirectory + fileName;

        File.Copy(sourceFile, destinationFile);

        GetFilesInDirectory();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SetImageDirectory();
        GetFilesInDirectory();
    }

    private void GetFilesInDirectory()
    {
        // Populate images in selection box

        lbxFiles.ItemsSource = null;

        string[] images = Directory.GetFiles(imageDirectory);
        string[] fileNames = new string[images.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < images.Length; i++)
        {
            fileNames[i] = images[i].Substring(images[i].LastIndexOf('\\') + 1);
        }

        lbxFiles.ItemsSource = fileNames;
    }

    private void SetImageDirectory()
    {
        // Set the directions to get into images
        string currentDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

        DirectoryInfo parent = Directory.GetParent(currentDirectory);

        DirectoryInfo grandparent = parent.Parent;

        currentDirectory = grandparent.FullName;

        imageDirectory = currentDirectory + "\\images";
    }

    private void lbxFiles_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // open selected file
        string fileName = lbxFiles.SelectedItem as string;

        if (fileName != null)
        {
            imgAnimal.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imageDirectory + "\\" + fileName, UriKind.Absolute));

        }
    }

    private void btn_Save_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a public variable in AddImage class and get it in the first window.

Comment: There is no AddImage class, just the XAML and the XAML.CS

Comment: Dude, `public partial class AddImage` is your AddImage class

Comment: I have re worked it to just display on the second window, but I have run into a problem where by the Image on the mainWindow wont display the image through the path

Comment: image_Vehicle = selectedVehicle.VehImage;